# How can I make dynamic import conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import

I am working on a project with Reactjs + Nextjs and I need that depending on a conditional a component should be imported dynamically or not.

Like this:

```js
const importMyComponent = isLiveBlog => ({
  image: isLiveBlog
    ? import('@path/to/the/component')
    : dynamic(() => import('@path/to/the/component'), { loading: ContentPlaceholder }),

});
```

With that method above I get an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `YourComponent`.
```

Comment: What is the useCase? Why not use `dynamic` all the time?

Comment: The use case according to what they tell me is SEO purposes. @vighnesh153

Comment: Is it a named or default component you are trying to import at `@path/to/the/component`?

Comment: @morganney a default one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using dynamic import in conditionaly you can use condition inside `dynamic()` method.as the example showing below.

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(
  () => {
    return isLiveBlog
      ? import("../components/TestOne")
      : import("../components/TestTwo");
  },
  {
    suspense: true,
  }
);

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DynamicComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```